A fantasy story with an imp in a box that paints pictures
There is just one detail that comes to my mind and I cannot connect it with any other memory of a fantasy story I read very, very long ago. I vaguely feel it was a long and intricate novel, but I may well be wrong.
One of the characters owns a box with which he takes pictures of what he finds interesting, as if it were a photo camera in our world. But inside it there is an imp with paint brushes and colours who paints the pictures very rapidly. IRCC, once the imp complains that the owner is taking too many pictures of sunsets and that he is running out of red paint.

@FuzzyBoots The red paint/sunsets may be a false memory. I might well have mixed up pink and red and wrongly reconstructed sunsets to explain the excessive use of red. I am possibly too puritan-minded to have remembered pink and "young ladies" from the Whore Pits. LOL

That sounds like the Discworld iconograph.

An iconograph is a wonderful device that allows you to make "instantaneous paintings". In fact, an imp with brushes, pencils and a good eye for colours is put in a box, and when you push the button, you open a little window on the box and the imp draws really fast what it sees through the opening. Salamanders are used when more light is necessary for the imp to paint a good picture. All but the cheapest of today's iconographs can paint in colour.
Imps have no imagination whatsoever, and as a result, paint very accurate pictures. They do whatever they are told so long as it is within the limits of their training, such as being able to "zoom" in and paint in very small detail, or even to paint the picture of a cart and its number if it exceeds the speed limit.

....

Theoretically the lifespan of the imp is endless, but the imps of the cheaper iconographs seem to disappear rather quickly. Independently of this, the painting colours used by the imp have to be refilled as they are used up, and the imps themselves require regular feeding, though they seem to be able to survive without any form of sustenance for several weeks.

The most likely quote is from The Color of Magic, following this passage.

A prolonged session at the Whore Pits produced a number of colourful and instructive pictures, a number of which Rincewind concealed about his person for detailed perusal in private. As the fumes cleared from his brain he began to speculate seriously as to how the iconograph worked.

....

The box said, "It's no good. I've run out of pink."
A hitherto unnoticed door opened in front of his eyes. A small, green and hideously warty humanoid figure leaned out, pointed at a colour-encrusted palette in one clawed hand, and screamed at him.
"No pink, See?" screeched the homunculus. "No good you going on pressing the lever when there's no pink, is there? If you wanted pink you shouldn't of took all those pictures of young ladies, should you? It's monochrome from now on, friend. Alright?"
"Alright. Yeah, Sure," said Rincewind. In one dim corner of the little box he thought he could see an easel, and a tiny unmade bed. He hoped he couldn't. "So long as that's understood," said the imp, and shut the door. Rincewind thought he could hear the muffled sound of grumbling and the scrape of a stool being dragged across the floor.

As noted in the comments, The Light Fantastic has another scene involving colors running out. No sunsets are mentioned, and black is indicated to be what the imp is running low on.

'This red star thing.'
'Right. It's very important that you —'
'Hallo? Hallo? Anyone out there?'
It was a small and squeaky voice and came from the picture box still slung around Twoflower's inert neck.
The picture imp opened his hatch and squinted up at Rincewind.
'Where's this, squire?' it said.
'I'm not sure.'
'We still dead?'
'Maybe.'
'Well, let's hope we go somewhere where we don't need too much black, because I've run out.' The hatch slammed shut.


Beat me to it. Was looking for the quote, but still haven't found it.

It is indeed Discworld ! Now I remember. The iconograph first belongs to Twoflower in The Color of Magic even if the "pink" incident is with Rincewind.

The imp runs out of red paint in The Light Fantastic.

@ClaraDíazSanchez Thanks, but the important point was to get the right series, and that was enough for me to find the name of Twoflower. The incident with the lack of paint was meant to help the other users.

@ClaraDíazSanchez: Thank you. Was at Thanksgiving festivities.

Yes, it was The Color of Magic.  Part of the joke is that the reader is led to believe that Twoflower is using technology akin to ours, i.e. he's a modern person visiting this fantasy world, and Rincewind's theory about the imp is the kind of theory a medieval fantasy wizard would come up with.  Then we find out the joke is on us, it's an imp after all.

The iconograph also has an important role in Feet of Clay, where Vimes has the imp zoom in to a ridiculous degree to see something in the victim's eye, referencing a similar scene in Blade Runner.

The iconograph also returns in The Truth, where an imp learns to "paint" using acid on metal plates, allowing the pictures to be run off on a printing press.

@DarthPseudonym: Yes, "technology" progresses as the Discworld series goes on, to the point that there are newspaper photographers and IIRC city watch crime-scene photographers.  And the clax (semaphore telegram relay towers) can transmit bitmap images slowly, at least in theory, I forget if that was just an idea someone had or if it was in occasional practical use by the last few books in the series for important news stories.

@PeterCordes The clacks being used to transmit images was explicitly mentioned as a real thing in universe in Monstrous Regiment (in a discussion that William de Worde and Otto Chriek have with the main characters of the story, where Lieutenant Blouse demonstrates an unexpected grasp of information theory when discussing it despite being from a country that was violently opposed to the clacks) and Going Postal (where it’s called out very specifically during the very beginning of the race between the post office and the clacks as an explanation for part of Moist’s grandstanding).

@workerjoe Yes, you are quite right. The joke was excellent, even though it was at the expense of the reader !
